# Округление результата при делении чисел с плавающей точкой

Tags: c++, математика, числа-с-плавающей-точкой, ieee-754

Известно, что все целые числа из отрезка `[-2**53, 2**53]` могут быть точно представлены числом IEEE-754 двойной точности. Если мы складываем, вычитаем или перемножаем два целых числа IEEE-754 двойной точности из указанного выше отрезка и точный вещественный результат также принадлежит указанному выше отрезку, то получившееся значение будет совпадать с точным вещественным результатом.

Меня интересует операция деления. Пусть `a` и `b` — числа IEEE-754 двойной точности, оба строго положительные целые и принадлежат указанному выше отрезку. Пусть также точный вещественный результат деления `a / b` **лежит между двумя целыми числами `n-1` и `n`**.

Будет ли результат деления `a / b` при вычислении в числах с плавающей точкой также строго меньше `n`? Если да, хотелось бы увидеть доказательство этого факта (можно ссылку на сайт/книгу, где можно почитать об этом). Если нет, то хотелось бы увидеть пример на котором в результате округления значение `n` достигается.

Если числа `a` и/или `b` не принадлежат отрезку `[-2**53, 2**53]`, то число `n` может быть достигнуто при вычислениях в числах с плавающей точкой. Например, пусть

```
a = 45'035'996'273'704'952; // (2**53 - 2) * 5 + 2;
b = 9'007'199'254'740'991;  //  2**53 - 1;
```

Точный вещественный результат равен примерно ([wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=45035996273704952+%2F+9007199254740991)):

```
4.999999999999999666933092612453...
```

В данном случае точный вещественный результат строго меньше `n = 5`. Но при вычислении в числах IEEE-754 двойной точности число `n` будет достигнуто. Пример:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <limits>
#include <cstdint>
using std::cout;
 
int main()
{
    typedef std::uint_fast64_t uint_type;
 
    double a, b, c;
    uint_type ta, tb, tc, ic;
 
    a = 45'035'996'273'704'952ULL; // (2**53 - 2) * 5 + 2;
    b = 9'007'199'254'740'991ULL;     //  2**53 - 1;
    c = a / b;
 
    ta = static_cast<uint_type>(a);
    tb = static_cast<uint_type>(b);
    tc = static_cast<uint_type>(c);
    ic = ta / tb;
 
    cout << std::setprecision(std::numeric_limits<double>::max_digits10) << std::scientific << std::boolalpha;
 
    cout << "a  == "  << a  << "\n";
    cout << "ta ==  " << ta << "\n\n";
 
    cout << "b  == "  << b  << "\n";
    cout << "tb ==  " << tb << "\n\n";
 
    cout << "c  = "   << c  << "\n";
    cout << "tc ==  " << tc << "\n";
    cout << "ic ==  " << ic << "\n";
 
    cout << "tc == ic: " << (tc == ic) << "\n\n";
 
    return 0;
}
```

[Вывод](https://ideone.com/ezehuP):

```
a  == 4.50359962737049520e+16
ta ==  45035996273704952

b  == 9.00719925474099100e+15
tb ==  9007199254740991

c  = 5.00000000000000000e+00
tc ==  5
ic ==  4
tc == ic: false
```

Comment: но ведь число `(2**53 - 2) * 5 + 2` располагается вне диапазона точного представления?

Comment: @user7860670, да, я так и написал: "Если числа `a` и/или `b` не принадлежат отрезку `[-2**53, 2**53]`, то число `n` может быть достигнуто при вычислениях в числах с плавающей точкой. Например, пусть ...".

Comment: ну так а к чему этот пример? попробуйте написать пример, перебирающий числа из диапазона точного представления и проверяющий это утверждение. числа большие и до полного перебора будет далеко, однако велика вероятность, что проблемный случай быстро найдется

Comment: @user7860670, пример для того, чтобы продемонстрировать, что в общем случае `n` достижимо. Я предполагаю, что если `a` и `b` из указанного отрезка, то `n` не достижимо. Я пробовал частично перебрать. Пример, опровергающий предположение не нашёл, но и перебрал я далеко не весь диапазон.

Answer (score 4):

IEEE-754 определяет несколько вариантов округления (для C/C++ смотри описания функций [`fegetround()`/`fesetround()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/fenv/feround)), но по умолчанию истинный результат должен округлятся к ближайшему значению, представимому в данном формате (а в случае равноудалённости таковых — к нечётному значению мантиссы).

> Будет ли результат деления a / b при вычислении в числах с плавающей точкой также строго меньше n?

Судя по всему так и есть, хотя доказательства и не мой конёк, но я всё же попробую кое-как строго это обосновать.

---

Итак, нам дано:

- [image: a, b \in \mathbb{N} \quad a,b < 2^{t+1}], где [image: t] — размерность мантиссы числа.
- [image: n-1 < {{a} \over {b}} < n \quad n \in \mathbb{N}]
- [image: div(a,b)] — функция деления чисел с плавающей точкой
- Число с плавающей точкой [image: q] представимо в виде [image: (1+{m \over 2^t}) \cdot 2^p, m \in \mathbb{Z}, 0 \le m < 2^t]
- ⇒ Интервал между числом [image: q] и следующим за ним представимым числом [image: \varepsilon = 2^{p-t}]

---

Предположим, что существуют a и b удовлетворяющие условиям выше и такие, что [image: div(a,b)=n].

Тогда, существует точное разложение вида:
[image: c={a \over b}=n - {k \over b}]
, где [image: k \in \mathbb{N}].

При этом [image: (1+{m \over 2^t}) \cdot 2^p \le c \le (1+{m+1 \over 2^t}) \cdot 2^p].
Заметим, что для нашего случая [image: p \ge 0] и ⇒ [image: c \ge 2^p].

По условию из стандарта округление в большую сторону должно происходить только если истинный результат отличается от итогового меньше, чем на половину интервала представимых значений.

[image: div(a,b) - c = n - n + {k \over b} < {1 \over 2} \cdot \varepsilon]

Далее пара нехитрых алгебраических преобраpований:

[image: {k \over b} < 2^{p-t-1}]

[image: b > k \cdot 2^{t+1-p}]

т.к. [image: k \in \mathbb{N}], то [image: b > 2^{t+1-p}]

[image: b \cdot 2^{p} > 2^{t+1}]

т.к. [image: c \ge 2^p], то [image: bc > 2^{t+1}]

---

**т.о. [image: a > 2^{t+1}]**

---

Таким образом, чтобы [image: div(a,b)] округлилось вверх до целого необходимым условием является, чтобы делимое было больше, чем [image: 2^{t+1}]. Что, очевидно, противоречит начальному условию.

---

**Дисклеймер:** В доказательстве могут быть ошибки. Я не написал пока ни одной монографии по программированию и не готов платить за обнаружение оных двоичными долларами; но исправления и уточнения приветствуются.